# joining on another table causes sum to be greater

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

when i join two tables together and get the sum, i am getting the correct figure:

```
select 
    d.accn_id,
    cast(d.load_date as DATE) as LoadDate,
    cast (d.final_rpt_date as DATE) as FinalReportDate,
    sum(p.paid_amt) as SumPaidAmt

from
    accn_demographics d
join 
    accn_payments p
on 
    d.ACCN_ID=p.ACCN_ID
where 
    p.POSTED='y'
    and p.PMT_DATE between '20120501' and '20120531'

group by 
    d.accn_id,
    d.load_date,
    d.final_rpt_date
```

however after i join ANOTHER table accn_payors:

```
select 
    d.accn_id,
    cast(d.load_date as DATE) as LoadDate,
    cast (d.final_rpt_date as DATE) as FinalReportDate,
    sum(p.paid_amt) as SumPaidAmt
    ,payors.PAYOR_ID
from
    accn_demographics d
join 
    accn_payments p
on 
    d.ACCN_ID=p.ACCN_ID
left join 
    accn_payors payors
on  
    payors.X_PAYOR_ID=p.X_PRICED_PAYOR_ID 
    and payors.ACCN_ID = p.ACCN_ID
where 
    p.POSTED='y'
    and p.PMT_DATE between '20120501' and '20120531'

group by 
    d.accn_id,
    d.load_date,
    d.final_rpt_date
    ,payors.PAYOR_ID
```

i am getting an overstatement of `sum(p.paid_amt)`

the question is how can i adjust my join so that i am not joining multiple times?

Comment: Well, the problem is that your join is returning multiple rows from payor for rows in accn_payments.  Can a payment have more than one payor?

Comment: jim, yes i guess, it can, how can i just grab the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of joining on accn_payors, you need to join on a SELECT statement that returns one row per accn_id. Depending on your requirements, this might work.

```
select accn_id, min(x_payor_id) x_payor_id
from payors
group by accn_id
```

Aliasing `min(x_payor_id)` with the same name lets the rest of the code work without modification. That might or might not be a good idea. It's a little misleading.

So instead of this . . .

```
left join 
    accn_payors payors
on  
    payors.X_PAYOR_ID=p.X_PRICED_PAYOR_ID 
    and payors.ACCN_ID = p.ACCN_ID
```

you'd do this . . .

```
left join 
    (select accn_id, min(x_payor_id)
     from payors
     group by accn_id) payors
on  
    payors.x_payor_id = p.x_priced_payor_id
    and payors.accn_id = p.accn_id
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work, but I don't know what would determine which payor_id you would want to get, so min() may not be the right function for you, maybe max() would?

```
SELECT * 

FROM (

select 
    d.accn_id,
    cast(d.load_date as DATE) as LoadDate,
    cast (d.final_rpt_date as DATE) as FinalReportDate,
    sum(p.paid_amt) as SumPaidAmt,
    min(p.X_PRICED_PAYOR_ID)


from
    accn_demographics d
join 
    accn_payments p
on 
    d.ACCN_ID=p.ACCN_ID
where 
    p.POSTED='y'
    and p.PMT_DATE between '20120501' and '20120531'

group by 
    d.accn_id,
    d.load_date,
    d.final_rpt_date
) payments
LEFT JOIN accn_payors payors
on  
    payors.X_PAYOR_ID=payments.X_PRICED_PAYOR_ID 
    and payors.ACCN_ID = payments.ACCN_ID
```